# kotlin's coRouter returns 404 instead of 405

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I use Kotlin + srpingframework webflux (6.0.7) and create a router like this:

```
@Configuration
class TestApi {

    @Bean
    fun testApiRouter(handler: TestApiHandler) = coRouter {
        "/api/v1/test".nest {
            GET("", handler::handle)
            // i tried to put filter here but it didn't work
        }
    }

}
```

So here I have the method "GET /api/v1/test".
But when I try to perform "POST /api/v1/test", I get 404 NOT_FOUND instead of 405 Method not allowed

I want to get 405 but it's unclear how I can set up that.

I've discovered that my matching process is finished in a method `ResourceWebHandler.handle` where the 404 error is raised. ResourceWebHandler is the last handler, RouterFunctionMapping works before.

I've also tried to set up `filter` inside my router, but it is called only when the one of routes matched exactly (by method and a path).